# Overriding == for immutable collections

Tags: c#, immutability

Suppose I have a class that is a readonly collection or immutable objects, e.g.

```
public class ReadOnlyInts : IReadOnlyCollection<int>
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<int> intCollection;
    public ReadOnlyInts(IEnumerable<int> ints)
    {
        intCollection = ints.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    #region IReadOnlyCollection<int> Methods
    // ...
    #endregion
}
```

Now, without some trickery on the part of the consumer neither the `intCollection` nor its members can change so the type is immutable. Going by [the MSDN guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), the type should overload `==`. However, it is not clear to me that these guidelines are intended to apply to collections as the .Net built in collections do not override even `.Equals`. I am worried then that overloading `==` as roughly `.SequenceEquals` will be unexepected behavior to other consumers.

Is it a good idea for deeply immutable collections to overload `==`?

Answer (score 1):

If you construct two **different** `ReadOnlyInts`, but they have the same content (perhaps created from the same `IEnumerable<int>` object) do you want them to be equal?  If so then you should overload `==` and check the contents for equality.  Otherwise it's just a reference comparison which will fail with two different but identical objects.